# systematically check vector.push_back for bad_allocs

Tags: c++

Is there an equivalent to `std::set_new_handler` for custom-handling `std::bad_alloc`s on vector `push_back` attempts ?

It would be very cumbersome to wrap every `push_back` site in a `try/catch` sandwich throughout the entire program !

More generally, I have a simple policy for all memory allocation issues : `std::terminate` (with a message), can I set this globally for all memory allocation ops (`new`, `push_back`, `resize`, ..) ?

**Answer** by [Konrad Rudolph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1968/konrad-rudolph): `std::set_new_handler` does actually take care of all allocation ops, since those implicitly use `new`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void handler(){
  std::cout << "Memory allocation failed, terminating\n";
  exit(55);
}

int main() {
  std::set_new_handler(handler);
  vector<size_t> v; while (true) v.resize(10000000000ul);
  // int *a =  new int[107374182400ul]; a[3] = 12;  // 100 GB
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could also write a global `operator new` — but what’s wrong with `std::set_new_handler`? This is literally its purpose. Apart from that, beware that some systems (including many Linux systems by default!) **never** throw `std::bad_alloc`, they handle allocation failure fundamentally differently; so your handler won’t catch allocation failures on those systems.

Comment: I'm specifically asking because `set_new_handler` specifically tends to the `new` operator only, not to the other memory consumers (`push_back`, `resize`,..). Or do you mean that the latter implicitly call `new`, so they automatically fall under the spell of `set_new_handler` ?

Comment: Yes, they all call `new` at *some* point — unless you provide a custom allocator which does something else.

Comment: Also, thank you for the heads-up about some animals out there not throwing `bad_alloc`s. The doc says the handler is called "whenever a memory allocation attempt fails", so I would hope that all allocation issues would go through my handler (bad_alloc or other).

Comment: Tested under VS2019 & gcc 10.2.0: an infinite loop of `push_back`s/`resize`s does go through the `set_new_handler`. That does it. (however `new int[107374182400ul]` fails as expected under gcc, but not under VS2019 !)

Answer (score 0):

You could provide a specific allocator for the vector that performs your terminate code under out of memory condition.

```
td::vector< MyObject*, my_custom_allocator > my_vector ;
```

Comment: Custom allocators where my saviors from ugly macros. As per Konrad's comment above, `set_new_handler` actually works for all allocation operations ! Thank you.